# Button text toggle in jquery

Tags: jquery, button, toggle

When i click ".pushme" button, it turns its text to "Don't push me". I want to turn the text again to "push me" when button is clicked again. How can i do that?

```
<html>

<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <button class='pushme'>PUSH ME</button>
    <script>
        $(".pushme").click(function () {
            $(this).text("DON'T PUSH ME");
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DQK4v/

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery Toggle Text?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155453/jquery-toggle-text)

Answer (score 217, accepted):

You can use `text` method:

```
$(function(){
   $(".pushme").click(function () {
      $(this).text(function(i, text){
          return text === "PUSH ME" ? "DON'T PUSH ME" : "PUSH ME";
      })
   });
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CBajb/

Comment: Can someone explain why having specific html inside the ``html`` function will not work? http://jsfiddle.net/CBajb/18/

Comment: if `PUSH ME` and `DON'T PUSH ME` are actually two paragraphs, then is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: Yes, there is. Use an object: `conditon ? obj.par1 : obj.par2`. Another option is toggling the visibility of the elements.

Comment: @undefined what is the point of the parameter "i"? I don't understand why it is needed but I know that it is needed since it does not work without it. I understand why text is needed but "i" is not used at all?

Comment: @gmonz `i` refers the index of iteration. We have to accept the first parameter for using the second parameter. That's how functions work! One can also use `this.textContent` instead of the second parameter of the callback function. Basically `text` here is equal to `this.currentText`, where `this` refers to a clicked `.pushme` element.

Comment: without jQuery in the HTML you can do: `<button onclick="this.innerHTML = (this.innerHTML === 'Hello')?  'Goodbye':'Hello';">Hello</button>`

Answer (score 21):

You could also use `.toggle()` like so:

```
$(".pushme").toggle(function() {
    $(this).text("DON'T PUSH ME");
}, function() {
    $(this).text("PUSH ME");
});
```

More info at http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/.

This way also makes it pretty easy to change the text or add more than just 2 differing states.

Comment: .toggle has been removed as of jquery 1.9. That's a shame. Looks quite nice!

Comment: @Relequestual It's true, unfortunately. Toggle still exists for hiding/showing elements http://api.jquery.com/toggle/ but this example would no longer work post 1.9. :(

Comment: @Relequestual There are pretty good alternatives, see, for example, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155453/jquery-toggle-text#17452139).

Answer (score 16):

Use a custom ID if possible if you would like to apply the action to only that button.

#### HTML

```
<button class="pushDontpush">PUSH ME</button>
```

#### jQuery

```
$("#pushDontpush").click(function() { 
    if ($(this).text() == "PUSH ME") { 
        $(this).text("DON'T PUSH ME"); 
    } else { 
        $(this).text("PUSH ME"); 
    }; 
});
```

Working CodePen: [Toggle text in button](https://codepen.io/audiobro/pen/NvpoKB)

Answer (score 8):

Use an if/else statement.. or ternary if you understand it

```
$(".pushme").click(function () {
    var $el = $(this);
    $el.text($el.text() == "DON'T PUSH ME" ? "PUSH ME": "DON'T PUSH ME");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dFZyv/

Answer (score 6):

With so many great answers, I thought I would toss one more into the mix. This one, unlike the others, would permit you to cycle through any number of messages with ease:

```
var index = 0,
    messg = [
        "PUSH ME", 
        "DON'T PUSH ME", 
        "I'M SO CONFUSED!"
    ];

$(".pushme").on("click", function() {
    $(this).text(function(index, text){
        index = $.inArray(text, messg);
        return messg[++index % messg.length];
    });
}​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​);​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DQK4v/2/

Answer (score 5):

```
$(".pushme").click(function () {
  var button = $(this);
  button.text(button.text() == "PUSH ME" ? "DON'T PUSH ME" : "PUSH ME")           
});
```

This ternary operator has an implicit return.
If the expression before `?` is `true` it returns `"DON'T PUSH ME"`, else returns `"PUSH ME"`

This if-else statement:

```
if (condition) { return A }
else { return B }
```

has the equivalent ternary expression:

```
condition ? A : B
```

Answer (score 4):

I preffer the following way, it can be used by any button.

```
<button class='pushme' data-default-text="PUSH ME" data-new-text="DON'T PUSH ME">PUSH ME</button>

$(".pushme").click(function () {
    var $element = $(this);
    $element.text(function(i, text) {
        return text == $element.data('default-text') ? $element.data('new-text')
                                                     : $element.data('default-text');
    });
});
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/PHG2a/)

Answer (score 3):

If you're setting the button text by using the 'value' attribute you'll need to set

- $(this).val()

instead of:

- $(this).text()

Also in my situation it worked better to add the JQuery direct to the onclick event of the button:

```
onclick="$(this).val(function (i, text) { return text == 'PUSH ME' ? 'DON'T PUSH ME' : 'PUSH ME'; });"
```

Comment: For me, this is only working every other button click.

Comment: A friend helped me figure out that it was because I had two event listeners. I was just pasting code from the other answer straight into a JS file, and I was calling the parent function from an onclick as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use math function to do this

```
var i = 0;
$('#button').on('click', function() {
    if (i++ % 2 == 0) {
        $(this).val("Push me!");
    } else {
        $(this).val("Don't push me!");
    }
});
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/9s7vro92/)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of incrementing the above example to infinity, you can use a simpler solution:

```
var i=0;
      $('#button').on('click', function() {
          if(i == 0){
            $(this).val("Don't push me!"); i = 1;
          }else{
            $(this).val("Push me!"); i = 0;
          }
      });
```