# jQuery change append onClick

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following jQuery code which locates the `ul` element on the page, hides any `li` items after the third item within that `ul` element and appends a *"Show More!"* text link which reveals/toggles the hidden list items when clicked.

```
$('ul')
    .find('li:gt(2)')
    .hide()
    .end()
    .append(
        $('<li>Show More!</li>').click( function(){
        $(this).siblings().toggle(500);
        })
    );
```

**An example of the script's functionality: http://jsfiddle.net/vf6j5/**

Here's what I'd like the script to do: When the hidden elements are revealed after *"Show More!"* is clicked, I'd like the *"Show More!"* text to be replaced with *"Show Less!"*. Doing this would be much more user friendly and make a bit more sense.

Any ideas on how this could be accomplished?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Button text toggle in jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13652835/button-text-toggle-in-jquery)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look on this:

```
$('ul')
        .find('li:gt(2)')
         .hide()
        .end()
        .append(
            $('<li class="title">Show More!</li>').click( function(){
            $(this).siblings().toggle(500);
                $(".title").html() === "Show More!"
                    ? $(".title").html("Show Less!")
                    : $(".title").html("Show More!")

            })
        );
```

[Worked code](http://jsfiddle.net/vf6j5/1/)

Comment: and if there are more than one `.title` elements?

Comment: Then we need change code. In this case that code work well. If you need help show me your example of problem.

Comment: The simple fact that you'd have to change it based on external elements shows that this solution is bad.

Answer (score 5):

http://jsfiddle.net/vf6j5/2/

```
$('ul')
    .find('li:gt(2)')
    .hide()
    .end()
    .append(
        $('<li>Show More!</li>').click(function() {
            var txt = $(this).text() == "Show More!" ? "Show Less!" : "Show More!";
            $(this).text(txt).siblings(':gt(2)').toggle(500);
        })
    );​
```

Comment: This is the only answer that toggles only the "extra" items, and doesn't toggle the first 3.

Answer (score 4):

```
$('ul').find('li:gt(2)').hide().end().append(
$('<li>Show More!</li>').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.siblings().toggle(500);
    $this.text(function(i, t) {
        return t === 'Show More!' ? 'Show Less!' : 'Show More!'
    })
}));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aGeMp/

Answer (score 3):

```
$('ul').find('li:gt(2)')
       .hide()
       .end()
       .append(
         $('<li>Show More!</li>').click(function() {
            $(this).text($(this).prev('li').is(':visible') ? 'Show More' : 'Show Less')
                   .siblings().toggle(500);
         })
       );​
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/vf6j5/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple - select the element you want to change and modify its text

```
$('#myButton').text('Show Less!');
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have `this` in the click event, just call `.text()` on it:

```
.... .click(function() {
  var that = $(this);
  that.siblings().toggle(500);
  that.text("Show less!");
});
```