# Jquery html() inside conditional check

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

these are extract of my code

```
<button>Hook It!</button>
```

and a bit of `JQuery`

```
$("ul li .tag_detail button").on('click', function() {
    console.log($(this).html());
    if ($(this).html() == 'Hook It!') {
        $(this).html('Unhook!');
    }
    if ($(this).html() == 'Unhook!') {
        $(this).html('Hook It!');
    }
});
```

Now, as you can see i want a toggling effect, i.e. when i click on button it should toggle between Hook It! and Unhook!.

The problem lies here

```
if($(this).html() == 'Hook It!')
```

here this condition never passes while console log prints Hook It!

```
console.log($(this).html());
```

Comment: you should use `else if`, put `else` before second `if`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Button text toggle in jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13652835/button-text-toggle-in-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the first if condition is satisfied then the content is change to `Unhook`, then the second one is satisfied because the content is changed by the first condition now the second block executes change the html back to `Hook It`

```
$("ul li .tag_detail button").on('click', function () {
    var text = $(this).text();
    console.log(text);
    if (text == 'Hook It!') {
        $(this).html('Unhook!');
    } else if (text == 'Unhook!') {
        $(this).html('Hook It!');
    }
});
```

another version could be

```
$("ul li .tag_detail button").on('click', function () {
    $(this).text(function(idx, text){
        return text == 'Hook It!' ? 'Unhook!' : 'Hook It!';
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple ternary operator should do the trick.

```
 $("ul li .tag_detail button").on('click',function(){
     var ths = $(this);
     ths.html(ths.html() == 'Hook It!' ? 'Unhook!' : 'Hook It!');
 });
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/GQeJ9/)

The problem with your code is you were updating the text value and then checking it again,reverting your changes.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($(this).text() == 'Hook It!') {
    $(this).text('Unhook!');
} else if ($(this).text() == 'Unhook!') {
    $(this).text('Hook It!');
}
```

Try the above. You are really dealing with text - not html.
The second condition should be an else as well

Answer (score 0):

```
$("ul li .tag_detail button").on('click', function() {
    console.log($(this).html());
    if ($(this).html() == 'Hook It!') {
        $(this).html('Unhook!');
    } else {
        $(this).html('Hook It!');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is your button is set to unhook! before you check unhook! and changed it to hook it! cause you used two `if` instead of `if else` so...

Please see the fixed code

```
$("ul li .tag_detail button").on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).html() == 'Hook It!') {
        $(this).html('Unhook!');
    }
    // change it to else if
    else if ($(this).html() == 'Unhook!') {
        $(this).html('Hook It!');
    }
});
```

or you can just...

```
$("ul li .tag_detail button").on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).html() == 'Hook It!') {
        $(this).html('Unhook!');
    } else {
        $(this).html('Hook It!');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please consider this:

JS:

```
$(function(){
    $('button').on('click', function() {
        if(this.innerHTML == 'Hook It')
            this.innerHTML = 'Unhook';
        else
            this.innerHTML = 'Hook It';
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-git2.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<button>Hook It
```

Fiddle here: http://jsbin.com/dadjj/1/edit?js,output.

A word of advice, before complaining about the missing html elements, you should watch [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WxmcDoAxdoY).

Answer (score 0):

Hate `if` statements? This is an alternative:

```
<button class="hook">Hook it!</button>
```

Separate hook/unhook actions into separate functions:

```
$('body').on('click', '.tag_detail button', function() {
    console.log('toggling');
    $(this).toggleClass('hook unhook');
})
.on('click', '.hook', function() {
    console.log('Clicked hooked!');
    $(this).text('Unhook it!');
})
.on('click', '.unhook', function() {
    console.log('Clicked un-hooked!');
    $(this).text('Hook it!');    
});
```