# JQuery change text on click (Also change back)

Tags: jquery, html, text, onclick, click

I have a div with a p inside it that says 'Fold it!'.  When I click the div, the p's text changes to 'Expand it'. How can I make so when I click the div for the second time it will change back to 'Fold it'?

HTML:

```
<div id="fold">
    <p id="fold_p">Fold it</p>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#fold").click(function () {
      $("#fold_p").text("Expand it");
    } )
  } );                  
</script>
```

Also, is it possible to make the transition a fade?
Any help is much appreciated :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Button text toggle in jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13652835/button-text-toggle-in-jquery)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#fold").click(function () {
        $("#fold_p").fadeOut(function () {
            $("#fold_p").text(($("#fold_p").text() == 'Fold it') ? 'Expand it' : 'Fold it').fadeIn();
        })
    })
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/BdQU2/1)**

Comment: Wow, this works great. but, is there any chance I can specify the fadeout duration?

Comment: Sure, just make the duration the first argument to the fade functions. See http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/BdQU2/2/. Ex: `$("#fold_p").fadeOut(2000,function () {`

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery ("#fold")    .click (function () {
        if (jQuery (this).children ("#fold_p").text() == "Fold it") {
                jQuery (this).children ("#fold_p").text("Expand It");
        }
        else {
             jQuery (this).children ("#fold_p").text("Fold it");        
        }
    });
```

Above is the sample code for your question.

Here is the fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/teZQA/

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/V6paG/)</kbd>

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var fold = $("#fold");
    fold.cliked = 1;// set initial click value to 1
    fold.click(function () {
    //change text o base of even or odd
        $("#fold_p").text((fold.cliked++ % 2 == 0) ? "Fold it" : "Expand it");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#fold").click( function (){
    if($(this).hasClass("helperClass")){
     $(this).find("p").text("Expand it");

    }else{
      $(this).find("p").text("Fold it");
    }
    $(this).toggleClass("helperClass");
  });
});                  
</script>
```