# Toggle span text on click with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to write a reusable script for toggling the text of an element on click.

I have it working on click but I can't get it to toggle back. Is there something wrong with my if statement?

```
<span class="js-textEdit" data-text="Show less">Show more</span>


$('.js-textEdit').click(function() {
  var oldText = $(this).text();
  var newText = $(this).attr('data-text');

  if ($(this).text(oldText)) {
    $(this).text(newText);
  } else {
    $(this).text(oldText);
  }
});
```

Here's a [JSFIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MzcMa/)

Also, is there a cleaner way to refactor this? Rather than use IDs and have to write a separate script for every element I want to use it on, I'm using a data attribute to determine the new text. Is the data attribute method a good approach?

Comment: when you click on the button for the second time old text is what currently in it, bind the current text to the element using data. https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Button text toggle in jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13652835/button-text-toggle-in-jquery).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('.js-textEdit').click(function () {
    var oldText = $(this).text();
    var newText = $(this).data('text');
    $(this).text(newText).data('text',oldText);
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/MzcMa/3/)** (and a slightly [better example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/MzcMa/5/) to show how it works on multiple elements )

Comment: @Moppy - My approach had to be smart? Ug, you never mentioned that you wanted it to be smart too ;)

Comment: Well, it was my approach really. Let's not get carried away here. All you did was move some things around :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the data-set to old text.

```
   $(this).attr('data-text',oldText);
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sentmca/MzcMa/1/)