# Request resubmitting on page refresh

Tags: javascript

I have a toggle button in my webpage, I submit an ajax request whenever user clicks on the toggle button, one thing is that when I refresh the page after sending the request the page tries to resubmit the request. How can I avoid this resubmission on refresh ?

I have html code as

```
 <div class="col-md-4">
 <input  class="toggleitem" data-onstyle="success"  checked type="checkbox"   data-toggle="toggle" >
  </div>

and jquery as
<script>

 $(function() {
        $('.toggleitem').change(function() {    

            sendrequest();
        })
    });
function sendrequest()
{
 if (confirm("do you want to continue with this request? ")) {
           $.ajax({
        url: 'https://home/systemstatus/',
        type:post,
        success: function (data) {
             console.log("success"+data);

        }
        });
}
</script>
```

Comment: <button type="button"> SUBMIT </button>

Comment: How does this help my question ?

Comment: well, type button won't submit the form he's in, type submit (default) will

Comment: how are you making the call. Is it in an onClick?

Comment: Its a toggle button , so I used event like ("#togglebutton").change(function(){}); as in jquery

Comment: im assuming then that you have function() { "function call here" }?

Comment: yes the function call has ajax request

Comment: It is unclear why a page refresh would trigger a button click. What kind of togglebutton? Something like this [togglebutton](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13652835/)? What functions are inside `.change(....)`. Without your code this is fishing in the dark.

Comment: I have updated my question with the code, i have used bootstrap toggle button