# how to do multiple task from a single button

Tags: javascript

I wanna make a button which shows two values hide and show. When we click the button hide it hides the content and it value changes to show and when we click show it displays the content.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Pay special attention to [How To Create MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The more effort you'll put into posting a good question: one which is easy to read, understand and which is [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - the chances are higher that it will attract the relevant people and you'll get help even faster. Good luck!

Comment: Please make sure you've done some research before asking. This is something that's usually covered in a tutorial

Answer (score 0):

I agree with previous comments. This is something typically taught in a tutorial. I was able to find an existing example in SO in less than 30 seconds.  Hope this helps:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/13652860/6288438