# jQuery - Toggle text to change on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I have a menu button, which when clicked will slide down a div below.

My menu is title "+ Open menu"

When the menu button is clicked my code changes the title to "+ Menu" to indicate that the menu is open.

When the user closes the menu I would like the title to revert back to "- Menu"

This is my HTML which defines the class, test in this case.

```
<span class="test">+ Open menu</span>
```

Here is my jQuery function, I cannot figure out how to revert the menu state.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".widget_head_type").click(function () 
{
    $(".widget_body_type").slideToggle("slow");
    $(".test").text("- Close menu");
});
```

});

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery Toggle Text?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155453/jquery-toggle-text)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
$(".widget_head_type").click(function () {
    $(".widget_body_type").slideToggle("slow");
    ($(".test").text() === "+ Open menu") ? $(".test").text("- Close menu") : $(".test").text("+ Open menu");
});
```

Comment: It's getting late ;) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    toggleText: function (a, b){
        var that = this;
            if (that.text() != a && that.text() != b){
                that.text(a);
            }
            else
            if (that.text() == a){
                that.text(b);
            }
            else
            if (that.text() == b){
                that.text(a);
            }
        return this;
    }
});
```

Use as:

```
$("#YourElementId").toggleText('After', 'Before');
```

Comment: although one liner solution would be this 
`$.fn.extend({
    toggleText: function(a, b){
        return this.text(this.text() == b ? a : b);
    }
});`
not exactly one line, i mean.
usage is same like yours
`$(".example").toggleText('Initial', 'Secondary');`

Answer (score 1):

Here is an interesting one based on the http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

HTML

```
<span class="test">+ Open menu</span>
<span class="test" style="display:none">- Close menu</span>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".widget_head_type").click(function () 
{
    $(".widget_body_type").slideToggle("slow");
    $(".test").toggle();
});
```

Simple, just toggles the all tags with class test whether hidden or visible.

Comment: plus one :) this is innovative

Answer (score 0):

[**WORKING FIDDLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/dYWA3/)

I've guessed at your html, and made some notes for alternatives, but you consider the following:

HTML:

```
<div class="some_parent_class">
    <div class="widget_head_type">
        <span class="test">+ Menu</span>
    </div>
    <div class="widget_body_type">
        Body
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('.widget_head_type').each(function () {
        // closures
        var $toggle = $(this);
        var $parent = $toggle.closest('.some_parent_class');
        var $target = $parent.find('.widget_body_type');
        var $label = $toggle.find('.test');
        var bIsTweening = false;
        // OR var $target = $toggle.next('.widget_body_type');
        // event methods (closures)
        var fClickToggle = function () {
            if (!bIsTweening) {
                bIsTweening = true;
                $target.slideToggle('slow', fToggleCallback);
            }
        };
        var fToggleCallback = function () {
            bIsTweening = false;
            fSetLabel();
        };
        var fSetLabel = function () {
            var sLabel = $label.text().replace('+', '').replace('-', '');
            sLabel = ($target.is(':visible') ? '-' : '+') + sLabel;
            $label.html(sLabel);
        };
        // handle event
        $toggle.click(fClickToggle);
        $target.hide();
        fSetLabel();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

had same issue and this is how i solved it: using your code example.

```
$(".widget_head_type").click(function () {
    $(".widget_body_type").slideToggle("slow");
    ($(".test").text() == "+ Open menu") ? $(".test").text("- Close menu") : $(".test").text("+ Open menu");
});
```

use two equal signs for comparison.