# How to show only certain height of div and show the rest of it when clicked

Tags: javascript

Here is my code: https://jsfiddle.net/ucffyp3v/43/

As stated, I would like to only show 50px in height of this div and show the rest once show more is clicked.

The js does not seem to be working to display the rest of the div.

```
$("document").ready(function(){
$(".show-more").click(function(){
if($(".mydiv").css("height")!="50px"){
  $(".mydiv").slideDown();
}
else{
  $(".mydiv").slideUp();
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is maybe you are looking for: [working link](https://jsfiddle.net/ucffyp3v/81/)

```
$( "document" ).ready(function() {
  $(".show-more").click(function(){
    if($(".mydiv").css("height") === "50px"){
      $(".mydiv").css("height", 'auto');
      $(".mydiv").slideDown();
    }
    else{
      $(".mydiv").css("height", '50px');
      $(".mydiv").slideUp();
    }
  });
});
```

But I suggest you can move `<h2>Hello</h2>` to make the scroll go smoothly.

Comment: Thank you so much, seriously you are a lifesaver!

Comment: Is it possible to make "show more" switch to "show less" when the div is expanded and switch back to "show more" when collapsed?

Comment: Yes. You can use `$(".show-more").html('show less');`. Check the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ucffyp3v/98/

Comment: Thanks so much :) I know I've already asked too much. But is there a way to make the text fade away at the end of the collapsed div only? And show normally with no fading when expanded?

Comment: Great! If you want to make effect. You can use jquery fadeIn(300), fadeOut(300) instead of show(), hide().https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_fade.asp

Comment: You really helped me out tonight and it means a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax error for start. It seems to be working.

https://jsfiddle.net/3kor5bup/2/a

```
$("document").ready(function() {
  $(".show-more").click(function() {
    if ($(".mydiv").css("height") != "50px") {
      $(".mydiv").slideDown();
    } else {
      $(".mydiv").slideUp();
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Syntax error : [Working Example](https://jsfiddle.net/ucffyp3v/60/)

```
$("document").ready(function(){
  $(".show-more").click(function(){
    if($(".mydiv").css("height")!="50px"){
      $(".mydiv").slideDown();
    }
    else{
      $(".mydiv").slideUp();
    }
  });
});
```

And i think you are looking for `onchange`,`slideToggle` function.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you would like to check this question here: [jQuery Toggle Text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155453/jquery-toggle-text)

There are a few nice examples there of what you are trying to achieve, like this fiddle here by the user @firstandlastpost:

https://jsfiddle.net/b5u14L5o/

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    toggleText: function(stateOne, stateTwo) {
        return this.each(function() {
            stateTwo = stateTwo || '';
            console.log(stateOne, stateTwo, $(this).text());
            $(this).text() !== stateTwo  && stateOne
            ? $(this).text(stateTwo)
            : $(this).text(stateOne);
        });  
    }
});

$('button').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleText('Show it!', 'Hide it!').next().toggle();
});
```

For your example, I adapted to this: https://jsfiddle.net/ucffyp3v/87/

Answer (score 0):

You can use slideToggle function, see this working sample:

https://jsfiddle.net/g0jy9Lhm/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".show-more").click(function(){
    $(".mydiv").slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
```