# Hiding and Showing specific text in div, jquery

Tags: html, jquery

I am having issues hiding and showing specific text, specifically "picked" and "show_hidden". In this task I must make picked hide and then be able to click on "should" to show the picked again. Any help would be greatly appreciated:)

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Coding Tasks</title>

    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("a").click(function() {
        $("#picked").toggle();
       });
      });
      $("a").click(function() {
        $("#show_hidden").toggle();

    });
  </script>
    <style>
        .important {
          font-weight: bold;
          font-size: xx-large;
        }
        .set_colour {
          color: blue;
        }
        .test
        {
            width: 500px;
        }
        div
        {
            padding-top: 3px; padding-right: 3px; padding-bottom: 3px; padding-left: 3px; margin-top: 3px; margin-right: 3px; margin-bottom: 3px; margin-left: 3px; border-top-color: navy; border-right-color: navy; border-bottom-color: navy; border-left-color: navy; border-top-width: thin; border-right-width: thin; border-bottom-width: thin; border-left-width: thin; border-left-style: solid; border-right-style: solid; border-top-style: solid; border-bottom-style: solid; height:200px;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
<p>Name: George Bob</p>

  <div>
  <p class="test">Test 1: Hide and Show</p>
   <p class="picked">When you click on <a href="#">this</a> all paragraphs of class 'picked' should take 1.5sec and hide</p>
   <p id="show_hidden"><a href="#">Should</a> should not hide and on click should show hidden</p>
   <p class="picked">This should hide as well</p>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `toggle()`needs a css class name as parameter. Define a css class with `display:none;`and add the name to toggle method.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery Toggle Text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155453/jquery-toggle-text)

Comment: I am struggling to do this, could you show me an example?

Comment: Very important is to include your <script></script> in the head tag of your html

Comment: @MakisMilas It is not nessecary, though is the recommended way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without any changes on **posted** HTML code:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".picked").click(function()
    {
        $(".picked").each(function()
        {
            $(this).hide();
        });
    });

    $("#show_hidden").click(function() {
        $(".picked").each(function()
        {
            $(this).show();
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have defined you 'picked' elements with a class, yet you selected them using an id.

You should update your selector this way:

```
$(".picked").toggle(); // select by class, not id
```

Another issue with your code is that both anchors are selected by the element type (i.e. `a`). This way there is no way to distinguish between the elements.

You can give them individual id's and then use those to select the appropriate element for showing / hiding other elements.

That is, you should define your anchors in a similar way to this:

```
<a id="hide-link" href="#">this</a>
```

and the second one:

```
<a id="show-link" href="#">Should</a>
```

Finally, you script should look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#hide-link").click(function() {
        $(".picked").hide();
    });

    $("#show-link").click(function() {
        $(".picked").show();
    });
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This makes sense and helps me understand, however when I go to run the new code that you suggested, when I click "this" and "should" nothing happens. Sorry I am a complete noob and probably sound really naieve.

Comment: Have you updated the HTML part as well? I mentioned you need to add id's to your anchor elements to differentiate between them.